# Sending JSON data (Twitter (Temboo)) from Processing to Arduino

Tags: json, arduino, port, processing

I'm working on a student project and trying to send JSON data (based on the twitter hashtag '#tune') from Processing to Arduino, but the method 'myPort.write(status);' isn't usable with JSON, I've looked around online but not sure what command to use - Am I on the right track? Here's the code:

Processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;  //Serial connection for Arduino
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.temboo.core.*;  // Temboo library
import com.temboo.Library.Twitter.Search.*;  // Temboo Twitter search library

// Create a session using your Temboo account application details
TembooSession session = new TembooSession("MYUSERNAME", "MYTEMBOOAPPNAME", "MYTEMBOOCODE");

// Setup objects
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
int portNo = 7;  // Define portNo as int
int baudRate = 9600;  // Define baudRate as int

void setup() {
  // Run the Tweets Choreo function
  runTweetsChoreo();
  String portName = Serial.list()[portNo]; // Setup String for port ([7] is the port number for my machine)
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, baudRate);  // Setting up serial port
}

void runTweetsChoreo() {
  // Create the Choreo object using your Temboo session
  Tweets tweetsChoreo = new Tweets(session);

  // Set credential
  tweetsChoreo.setCredential("ArduinoUkulele");

  // Set inputs

  // Run the Choreo and store the results
  TweetsResultSet tweetsResults = tweetsChoreo.run();

  // retrieve the results as JSON
  JSONObject results = parseJSONObject(tweetsResults.getResponse());

  // retrieve the statuses from the results
  JSONArray statuses = results.getJSONArray("statuses");

  // loop through the statuses
  for (int i = 0; i < statuses.size(); i++){
    JSONObject status = statuses.getJSONObject(i);
    println(status.getString("text"));
    println(" -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- ");
    myPort.write(status);  // THIS IS THE CODE NOT WORKING WITH JSON
  }
}
```

Arduino:

```
char val; // Data received from the serial port
int ledPin = 13; // Set the pin to digital I/O 13

void setup(){
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // Set pin as OUTPUT
  Serial.begin(9600); // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available()) { // If data is available to read,
    val = Serial.read(); // read it and store it in val
    Serial.println(val);
    delay(10); // Wait 10 milliseconds for next reading
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm just looking for a certain command - once I've received the data I'm just looking to turn the LED on based on a new hashtag being receieved. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Arthur

Comment: I don't know Processing, but it seems to me as if the `write` method of `Serial` does not take a JSON object, but a String. Have you tried calling `myPort.write(status.toString());`? Also, please post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

**write()** method cannot take **JSONObject** as input, only **byte[]**, **String**. But you already have everything you need: just use **getString()** method as you are doing it two lines above (using appropriate key string, which you should know from API that you are using on top of JSON):

```
 myPort.write(status.getString("text"));
```